# How to get dateTime in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, datepicker

I have a column in my table with data type 'dateTime'

```
$table->dateTime('StartDate');
```

In my view I have 3 field

```
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <p>Tanggal Mulai</p>
    <div class="input-group date col-md-8" style="float: left;" id="StartDate">
        <input type='text' name="StartDate" class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group time col-md-4">
        <input style="width: 30px; height: 35px;" maxlength="2" name="jamstart"
                     value="" class="number" type="text" size="7"> :
        <input style="width: 30px; height: 35px;" maxlength="2" name="menitstart"
                     class="number" type="text" size="7" value=""> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

in

```
<div class="input-group date col-md-8" style="float: left;" id="StartDate">
    <input type='text' name="StartDate" class="form-control"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

will display calendar and I only can choose the date.
and in

```
<div class="input-group time col-md-4"> 
    <input style="width: 30px; height: 35px;" maxlength="2" name="jamstart"
                 value="" class="number" type="text" size="7"> : 
    <input style="width: 30px; height: 35px;" maxlength="2" name="menitstart"
                 class="number" type="text" size="7" value=""> 
</div>
```

will display textbox and I can input the hour and the minute.

So, how can I concatenate between the date and the hour and the minute to store the data in database

Comment: your code.. looks interesting, lots stripes. what do you mean with *concatenate between the date and the hour and the minute* ..? have you checked the [Carbon's Docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)? there exists `Carbon::create($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second, $tz);`

Comment: in my table, if I request startDate.. when I store the data, it will display like 2017-10-02 00:00:00.. I can not get the time.. so, I make two text box to get the hour and the minute.. So, if I store the data, I will get 2017-10-02 10:08:00 in my database

Comment: hi there, can you please post your code for storing the data in database

Comment: `2017-10-02 00:00:00` is not the issue. Once you fetch your data through Eloquent, it will automatically initiated as `Carbon` instance and you could format it as shown in the [Carbon's Docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you are entering date, hour and minute in your form.

Just do:

```
$date='2016-12-20';
$hour=10;
$second=26;
$res= Carbon::parse($date.''.$hour.':'.$second)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
dd($res);
```

Output will be:

```
"2016-12-20 10:26:00"
```

Comment: @BagusTesa.you mean no need to install ?.it installed by default ?

Comment: yes, if you are interested, you can take a look on Laravel's [composer.json](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/composer.json#L26). Not to mention it is stated explicitly in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators).

Comment: @BagusTesa.okay.thanks.i updaed answer .once i need to check becasue i usually installing carbon.will let you know whats there in laravel 5.5

Comment: well, fyi, its been there since Laravel 4, can refer on its [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#date-mutators).

Comment: @BagusTesa.ya sure.thanks for the link.i will check later :)